# Sorting a linked list of 0s, 1s and 2s in java not working

Tags: java, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am completely new to this programming world and to java and i was trying my hands at linked lists and came up with a problem while trying to sort a linked list of 0s,1s and 2s. Can anyone please specify what i am doing wrong? I am attaching my code over here.The thing is based on my logic it should work properly but unfortunately it's actually returning the list as it is without sorting.

**Sort a linked list of 0s, 1s and 2s**

```
class LinkedList
{
    Node head; 
    class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d) {
          data = d; 
         next = null;
       }



    Node sortList(Node h)
        {
    if(h!=null || h.next!=null)
    {
            return h;
    }
    Node zero = new Node(0);
    Node  one = new Node(0);
    Node  two = new Node(0);
    Node  curr = h;

    while(curr!=null)
    {
        if(curr.data == 0)
        {
            zero.next = curr;
            zero = zero.next;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        else if(curr.data == 1)
        {
            one.next = curr;
            one = one.next;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        else
        {
            two.next = curr;
            two = two.next;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }

    zero.next = (one.next !=null) ? (one.next): (two.next);
    one.next = two.next;
    two.next = null;
    h = zero.next;
    return h;


}               

    /* Inserts a new Node at front of the list. */
    public void push(int new_data)
    {

        Node new_node = new Node(new_data);

        new_node.next = head;


        head = new_node;
    }

    void printList(Node h)
    {
        Node temp = h;
        while (temp != null)
        {
        System.out.print(temp.data+" ");
        temp = temp.next;
        } 
        System.out.println();
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();


        llist.push(0);
        llist.push(1);
        llist.push(0);
        llist.push(2);
        llist.push(1);
        llist.push(1);
        llist.push(2);
        llist.push(1);
        llist.push(2);

        System.out.println("Linked List before sorting");
        llist.printList(llist.head);

        Node h=llist.sortList(llist.head);

        System.out.println("Linked List after sorting");
        llist.printList(h);
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all the sort function exit imminently without sorting because the `if(h!=null || h.next!=null)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you meant in your code but I tried to do it with as less changes as can

I introduce a new function for merging two lists

```
private Node merge(Node list1, Node list2){
    if (list1.next == null && list2.next == null)
        return new Node(0);
    else if (list1.next == null)
        return list2;
    else if (list2.next == null)
        return list1;
    else {
        Node curr = list1.next;
        while (curr.next != null){
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        curr.next = list2.next;
        return list1;
    }
}
```

and changed the sort function to

```
Node sortList(Node h)
{
    if (h == null || h.next == null)
        return h;

    Node zero = new Node(0);
    Node one = new Node(1);
    Node two = new Node(2);
    Node curr = h;
    Node nextNode;

    while(curr.next != null) {
        nextNode = curr.next;

        if(curr.data == 0)
        {
            curr.next = zero;
            zero = curr;
        }
        else if(curr.data == 1)
        {
            curr.next = one;
            one = curr;
        }
        else
        {
            curr.next = two;
            two = curr;
        }
        curr = nextNode;
    }

    Node tmpList = merge(zero, one);
    h = merge(tmpList,two);
    return h;


}
```

this problem has several solutions and some of them are far more easy, to name a few

- you can iterate over the list and count the occurrences of 0s,1s and 2s and build a new list with this data
- you can used various [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and implement them